# How do you recurse in JSX / React [material-ui]?

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I tried so many ways, so many articles, and I everytime I try some examples.. i get a failure to compile.  The closest I have gotten is for the top most node to display (Animals) and that is it.

I am hoping recurse through the 'children', if it exists... as the last item will not have a child... and create a sort of nested list box using material-ui list/checkbox

what.. the flux.. am i doing wrong?

like i said.. i can get the first item (Animals) to pull no problems... I just cannot get a recursive process going. =(

Header.js calls Sidebar.js (where i want the recursion)

Header.js:

```
import React from 'react';
import Sidebar from './Sidebar.js';

const returnedjson = [
{
    "className":"taxonomy"
    ,"description":"animals.. like meat, you know."
    ,"name": "Animal"
    ,"keyname": "ANIMAL"
    ,"key":1
    ,"children:":[
        {
            "className":"taxonomy"
            ,"description":"Feathers and fly."
            ,"name": "Bird"
            ,"keyname": "BIRD"
            ,"key":1
            ,"children":[
                {
                    "className":"taxonomy"
                    ,"description":"bawk bak"
                    ,"name": "Chicken"
                    ,"keyname": "CHICKEN"
                    ,"key":1
                    ,"children":[
                        {
                            "className":"taxonomy"
                            ,"description":"Meat"
                            ,"name": "Meat"
                            ,"keyname": "MEAT"
                            ,"key":2
                            ,"children":[
                                {
                                    "className":"taxonomy"
                                    ,"description":"Breast"
                                    ,"name": "Breast"
                                    ,"keyname": "BREAST"
                                    ,"key":1
                                }
                                ,   {
                                    "className":"taxonomy"
                                    ,"description":"wing"
                                    ,"name": "Wing"
                                    ,"keyname": "WING"
                                    ,"key":2
                                },  {
                                    "className":"taxonomy"
                                    ,"description":"Drumstick"
                                    ,"name": "Drumstick"
                                    ,"keyname": "DRUMSTICK"
                                    ,"key":3
                                }
                            ]
                        }
                        ,{
                            "className":"taxonomy"
                            ,"description":"Harvest"
                            ,"name": "Harvest"
                            ,"keyname": "HARVEST"
                            ,"key":1
                            ,"children":[
                                {
                                    "className":"taxonomy"
                                    ,"description":"Egg"
                                    ,"name": "Egg"
                                    ,"keyname": "EGG"
                                    ,"key":1
                                }
                                ,   {
                                    "className":"taxonomy"
                                    ,"description":"Egg"
                                    ,"name": "Egg White"
                                    ,"keyname": "EGG WHITE"
                                    ,"key":2
                                },  {
                                    "className":"taxonomy"
                                    ,"description":"Egg"
                                    ,"name": "Egg Yolk"
                                    ,"keyname": "EGG YOLK"
                                    ,"key":3
                                }
                            ]
                        }
                    ]
                }
            ]
        }
        ,   {
            "className":"taxonomy"
            ,"description":"Like a cow, deer, elk."
            ,"name": "Hooven"
            ,"keyname": "HOOVEN"
            ,"key":2
            ,"children":[
                {
                "className":"taxonomy"
                ,"description":"Moo"
                ,"name": "Cow"
                ,"keyname": "COW"
                ,"key":1
                ,"children":[
                    {
                        "className":"taxonomy"
                        ,"description":"Meat"
                        ,"name": "Meat"
                        ,"keyname": "MEAT"
                        ,"key":2
                        ,"children":[
                            {
                                "className":"taxonomy"
                                ,"description":"Flank"
                                ,"name": "Flank"
                                ,"keyname": "FLANK"
                                ,"key":1
                            }
                            ,   {
                                "className":"taxonomy"
                                ,"description":"rump"
                                ,"name": "Rump"
                                ,"keyname": "RUMP"
                                ,"key":2
                            },  {
                                "className":"taxonomy"
                                ,"description":"Shank"
                                ,"name": "Shank"
                                ,"keyname": "SHANK"
                                ,"key":3
                            }
                        ]
                    },{
                        "className":"taxonomy"
                            ,"description":"Harvested"
                            ,"name": "Harvest"
                            ,"keyname": "HARVEST"
                            ,"key":1
                            ,"children":[
                                {
                                    "className":"taxonomy"
                                    ,"description":"Milk"
                                    ,"name": "Milk"
                                    ,"keyname": "MILK"
                                    ,"key":1
                                }
                                ,   {
                                    "className":"taxonomy"
                                    ,"description":"half and half"
                                    ,"name": "Half and Half"
                                    ,"keyname": "HALF AND HALF"
                                    ,"key":2
                                },  {
                                    "className":"taxonomy"
                                    ,"description":"butter"
                                    ,"name": "Butter"
                                    ,"keyname": "BUTTER"
                                    ,"key":3
                                }
                            ]
                    }

                ]
            }]
        }
    ]
}
]

class Header extends React.Component{
    render(){
        let taxonomyarray=returnedjson
            return(

                <div>
                <Sidebar taxonomyarray={taxonomyarray} />
                </div>
                );
            }




}

export default Header;
```

Sidebar.js

```
import React from 'react';
import { makeStyles } from '@material-ui/core/styles';
import List from '@material-ui/core/List';
import ListItem from '@material-ui/core/ListItem';
import ListItemText from '@material-ui/core/ListItemText';
import ListItemIcon from '@material-ui/core/ListItemIcon';
import Checkbox from '@material-ui/core/Checkbox';


function SidebarList({ taxonomyarray }) {
  return (
    <div className="list">
      <List disablePadding dense>
        {taxonomyarray.map(
          ({ 
            className
            , name
            , keyname
            , description
            , key
            , children
            , value
          }) => 
            (

              <ListItem className ={className} key={key} button>
                <ListItemIcon>
                  <Checkbox
               // checked={checked.indexOf(value) !==-1}
                    tabIndex={-1}
                    disableRipple
                  />
                </ListItemIcon>
                <ListItemText
                  primary={name}
                  secondary={description}
                  key ={key}
                />
                </ListItem>

          ))}
      </List>
    </div>
  )
}

function Sidebar({ taxonomyarray }){
  console.log({taxonomyarray});
    return(
      <SidebarList taxonomyarray={taxonomyarray}/>
    )
  }



export default Sidebar
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can do this by mapping over the JSON with a recursive function. Not sure exactly what you want to render for each item, it could get a bit more complicated depending on that, but I made a basic example [here](https://codesandbox.io/s/quizzical-hugle-xpe7p).

Note there is also what I assume is a typo in the top level item. The key is `"children:"` instead of `children`.

Comment: thats what i was missing.

{item.children && item.children.map(recurse)}

it works perfectly.